# Is there a way to display error message on the screen without using model class and having only view and controller using asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have a view with cshtml and controller, from view javascript is called to post the data to the controller and the required operation happens. But as I input the negative numbers I need a validation to be performed either on the javascript or at the backend like controller to throw a validation message. And there is **no submit button** in this case and Jquery should not be used. Also my javascript is as below which takes the form data to send to controller

```
 <script>

function Assets(ev) {
    var request;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            //New browsers.
            request = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var formData = new FormData(document.forms.assets); //here instead of forms name I want to pass //the id of the 2 input fields and send that for operation in the controller. 
        }
        if (request != null) {
            var url = "Home/TotalAssets";
            request.open("POST", url, false);
            request.send(formData)
            
        }
    
        totalAssets.value = request.response;
    }
    </script>
</script>

<form name="property">
           
            <table>
                  
                <tr>
                    <td>  Property1  </td>
                    <td> $<input name="property1" type="number" onchange="Assets(event)" value="2000.00" /></td>

                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>  property2  </td>
                    <td> $<input type="number" onchange="Assets(event)" name="property2  " value="4000.00" /></td>

                </tr>
 <tr>


                    <td>$ <input type="number" readonly="readonly" name="totalProperty" id="totalProperty" onchange="Assetscalculate(event)"/></td>

                </tr>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to send the data back to a controller to validate, a simple Javascript could accomplish that on the front end.

Your HTML.

```
<form name="property">
       
        <table>
              
            <tr>
                <td>  Property1  </td>
                <td> $<input name="property1" type="number" onchange="Assets(this.value)" value="2000.00" /></td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>  property2  </td>
                <td> $<input type="number" onchange="Assets(this.value)" name="property2  " value="4000.00" /></td>

            </tr>
<tr>


                <td>$ <input type="number" readonly="readonly" name="totalProperty" id="totalProperty" /></td>

            </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

On your JAVSCRIPT

```
<script>
function Assets(value){
  if (value < 0){
   //Do something, such as Alert("Value is less than zero") or update a <span> to show the error message.
   alert("Value is less than zero");
  }else{
     var prop1 = document.getElementName("property1");
     var prop2 = document.getElementName("property2");
     var prop3 = document.getElementName("totalProperty");
     prop3.value = prop1.value + prop2.value;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This works. I have used span to display message on screen.So I can put red color code for the message displayed inside span ?

Comment: Yes, style the <span> with any color you want.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the javascript

```
<script>
function Assets(value){
  if (value < 0){
    document.getElementById('item1').innerHTML = "Please enter positive numbers."
  }else{
     var prop1 = document.getElementName("property1");
     var prop2 = document.getElementName("property2");
     var prop3 = document.getElementName("totalProperty");
     prop3.value = prop1.value + prop2.value;
  }
}
</script>
```

Worked